# Moodle - how to hide an assignment's description if the user has already submitted an assignment

Tags: submit, hide, variable-assignment, moodle

I am using Moodle 2.9.2. The assignment activity.

[image]

I want to NOT display the assignment description if the user has already submitted the assignment for marking. Now why would I want to do such a thing?? The reason for this is that the assignment description contains a form which I want the user to fill in once. And the user is expected to upload a file attachment as part of the fulfilment of the assignment submission. So after the file has been uploaded and the assignment has been submitted, the user should not access the form (i..e, assignment description) anymore.

I have done my homework. I have already narrowed the ground zero code down to the

```
public function render_assign_header(assign_header $header) {
...
}
```

of the file mod/assign/renderer.php. What I need is a way to detect that the user has already submitted the assignment for marking, and if so, don't display the description section. Basically, do nothing but whistle the Dixie (Line 235).

However, if the user has yet to submit the assignment, then show the assignment header title and description in all its glory (lines 238 to 252).

So here's my code ...
[image: function render_assign_header of class mod_assign_renderer of /mod/assign/renderer.php]

...which fails spectacularly. Like my programming lecturer used to say when he wanted to console us, "at least the idea is there".

Any Moodle programming guru able to assist me here? I need some tips/help/pointers/skeleton code/real code on line 233.

Regards
Frankie Kam 
BTW, the origins of the madness of my method lies here: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=343136

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way, but you could do this:

```
global $USER;
    $assign = new \assign($this->page->context, $this->page->cm, $this->page->course);
    $submission = $assign->get_user_submission($USER->id, false);
    if (!$submission || $submission->status != ASSIGN_SUBMISSION_STATUS_SUBMITTED)
    {
    //header here
    }
```

e.g.

```
/*
 * Render the header.
 *
 * @param assign_header $header
 * @return string
 */
public function render_assign_header(assign_header $header) {
    $o = '';

    if ($header->subpage) {
        $this->page->navbar->add($header->subpage);
    }

    $this->page->set_title(get_string('pluginname', 'assign'));
    $this->page->set_heading($this->page->course->fullname);

    $o .= $this->output->header();

    global $USER;
    $assign = new \assign($this->page->context, $this->page->cm, $this->page->course);
    $submission = $assign->get_user_submission($USER->id, false);
    if (!$submission || $submission->status != ASSIGN_SUBMISSION_STATUS_SUBMITTED)
    {

        $heading = format_string($header->assign->name, false, array('context' => $header->context));
        $o .= $this->output->heading($heading);
        if ($header->preface) {
            $o .= $header->preface;
        }

        if ($header->showintro) {
            $o .= $this->output->box_start('generalbox boxaligncenter', 'intro');
            $o .= format_module_intro('assign', $header->assign, $header->coursemoduleid);
            $o .= $header->postfix;
            $o .= $this->output->box_end();
        }

    }

    return $o;
}
```

Comment: Super! Many thanks. But I have to try this out to see if it works. I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt as appreciation for your time and effort. ;-)